# Sort Images by Number in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

I am trying to get my image slides to display in order by number with the following:

```
$image=array();
        $img_folder = $params->get('path');

        mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000);

        if(is_dir($img_folder)){
            krsort($file);
            $imgs = dir($img_folder);
            while ($file = $imgs->read()) {
               if ((eregi("gif", $file) || eregi("jpg", $file) || eregi("png", $file)))
                 $image[] = "$file";

            } closedir($imgs->handle);
            print_r($image);
            return $image;          
        }
```

However, the array works but the order is off:

Array ( [0] => Slide1.png [1] => Slide10.png [2] => Slide11.png [3] => Slide12.png [4] => Slide13.png [5] => Slide14.png [6] => Slide15.png [7] => Slide16.png [8] => Slide17.png [9] => Slide18.png [10] => Slide19.png [11] => Slide2.png [12] => Slide20.png [13] => Slide21.png [14] => Slide22.png [15] => Slide23.png [16] => Slide24.png [17] => Slide25.png [18] => Slide26.png [19] => Slide27.png [20] => Slide28.png [21] => Slide29.png [22] => Slide3.png [23] => Slide30.png [24] => Slide31.png [25] => Slide4.png [26] => Slide5.png [27] => Slide6.png [28] => Slide7.png [29] => Slide8.png [30] => Slide9.png )

If I put `natsort($image);` after `$image[] = "$file";` the order is correct but the array is off:

Array ( [0] => Slide1.png [11] => Slide2.png [22] => Slide3.png [25] => Slide4.png [26] => Slide5.png [27] => Slide6.png [28] => Slide7.png [29] => Slide8.png [30] => Slide9.png [1] => Slide10.png [2] => Slide11.png [3] => Slide12.png [4] => Slide13.png [5] => Slide14.png [6] => Slide15.png [7] => Slide16.png [8] => Slide17.png [9] => Slide18.png [10] => Slide19.png [12] => Slide20.png [13] => Slide21.png [14] => Slide22.png [15] => Slide23.png [16] => Slide24.png [17] => Slide25.png [18] => Slide26.png [19] => Slide27.png [20] => Slide28.png [21] => Slide29.png [23] => Slide30.png [24] => Slide31.png ) 
I need them to order Slide1 - Slide30, not like listed above.  I could change the names from numeric (Slide1) to alphabetic (SlideA) but would like to keep this naming convention.  Is there a way to do this without changing the image names?

This image slide is a "how to" slide show.

Comment: `eregi` is removed in php7.

Comment: We are using PHP Version 5.4.14 at the moment becuase Joomla 3.4 does not support PHP 7 on this version of Joomla
@MuhammedM.- I tried that and it works but it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick!!!

Just after

`$image[] = "$file";`

I added

`sort($image, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);`

This correctly orders the images in the array and the order:

Array ( [0] => Slide1.png [1] => Slide2.png [2] => Slide3.png [3] => Slide4.png [4] => Slide5.png [5] => Slide6.png [6] => Slide7.png [7] => Slide8.png [8] => Slide9.png [9] => Slide10.png [10] => Slide11.png [11] => Slide12.png [12] => Slide13.png [13] => Slide14.png [14] => Slide15.png [15] => Slide16.png [16] => Slide17.png [17] => Slide18.png [18] => Slide19.png [19] => Slide20.png [20] => Slide21.png [21] => Slide22.png [22] => Slide23.png [23] => Slide24.png [24] => Slide25.png [25] => Slide26.png [26] => Slide27.png [27] => Slide28.png [28] => Slide29.png [29] => Slide30.png [30] => Slide31.png )

Answer (score 3):

NatSort is what you are looking for.

just use `natsort($image);`

You can reference it at:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.natsort.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use **natsort()** function

[natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

e.g.

```
$array1 = array("img12.png", "img10.png", "img2.png", "img1.png");

 natsort($array);

 print_r($array);
```

This way you will get out put is :

```
Array ( [3] => img1.png [2] => img2.png [1] => img10.png [0] => img12.png )
```

You can also use [natcasesort($image)](http://php.net/natcasesort). It sort an array using a case insensitive "natural order" algorithm.

Comment: Manually adding the image names in the array is not an option cause it duplicates the images in the array.  Plus this slide is a module of Joomla so that would not work across the board.

Comment: you should use natsort or natcasesort which you found appropriate just before return. Please try once.

Comment: Using the following code:
`$image=array();
    $img_folder = $params->get('path');
   
   mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000);

   if(is_dir($img_folder)){
    krsort($file);
    $imgs = dir($img_folder);
    while ($file = $imgs->read()) {
       if ((eregi("gif", $file) || eregi("jpg", $file) || eregi("png", $file)))
      $image[] = "$file";
      natcasesort($image);
    
    } closedir($imgs->handle);
    print_r($image);
    return $image;   
   }`

Comment: I still return the same results:
Array ( [0] => Slide1.png [11] => Slide2.png [22] => Slide3.png [25] => Slide4.png [26] => Slide5.png [27] => Slide6.png [28] => Slide7.png [29] => Slide8.png [30] => Slide9.png [1] => Slide10.png [2] => Slide11.png [3] => Slide12.png [4] => Slide13.png [5] => Slide14.png [6] => Slide15.png [7] => Slide16.png [8] => Slide17.png [9] => Slide18.png [10] => Slide19.png [12] => Slide20.png [13] => Slide21.png [14] => Slide22.png [15] => Slide23.png [16] => Slide24.png [17] => Slide25.png [18] => Slide26.png [19] => Slide27.png [20] => Slide28.png [21]

Comment: where are you using natsort() ? just write before return $image; like natsort($image); return $image;

Comment: I put `natcasesort($image);` just before `return $image;` with the same results; array is correct, order is wrong.  If I put `natcasesort($image);` just after `$image[] = "$file";`, the order is correct but the array is off.

Comment: what about natsort() only?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know about `natsort()`, this should do it too though..

```
$imgs = scandir(dir($img_folder));
$sorted = array();
foreach($imgs as $img){
    $index = intval(trim($img, "Slide.png"));
    $sorted[$index] = $img;
}
ksort($sorted);
$sorted = array_values($sorted);
```